# Angular recorrer Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

Tengo un objeto

```
[
  {
    id:  "73639888",
     tipo:  "1",
     nombre:  "rodolfo rodolfo rodolfo"
  }
]
```

Y lo recorro de esta manera

```
for (const item of this.usuarios) {
   this.id = item.id;
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

El problema esta en que en si la respuesta que quiero leer es:

```
{
 error:  false,
 mensaje:  "Proceso exitoso",
 usu:[
    {
        id:  "73639888",
         tipo:  "1",
         nombre:  "rodolfo rodolfo rodolfo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No hay referencias en la pregunta a Angular más allá del título. No acabo de entender el problema: ¿es el último trozo de código una estructura en una respuesta AJAX? ¿Quieres extraer el atributo usu y recorrerlo?

Comment: Creo que lo que desea hacer el OP es construir un nuevo objeto, con las propiedades **error** y **message**, además de mantener el arreglo... creo

Comment: ya tengo el objeto usu, quiero recorrerlo y extraer sus datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno guardo el usuario en el servicio usuario.

```
this.servicio.login(formData).subscribe(
  usuario => {
    this.usuarioservicio.setUsuarioLogeadoen(usuario);
  }
);
```

Aquí el servicio.

```
setUsuarioLogeadoen(usuario: Usuario[]): void {
this.UsuarioLogeado = usuario;
localStorage.setItem('usuario', JSON.stringify(usuario));

}
getUsuarioLogeadoen() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario'));
}
```

Aqui lo traigo para procesarlo

```
const usuarios: Usuario[];
const usuario = this.usuarioservicio.getUsuarioLogeadoen();
Object.keys(usuario).map((key) => {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(usuario[key]);
  if (key === 'usu') {
    usuarios = usuario[key];
  }
});
```

Comment: y si agregas una explicación?